# subprocess.popen making the cgi script stuck

Tags: python, apache, subprocess, cgi-bin

When opening the page with following code the page keeps loading forever..

```
import cgitb
import subprocess,shlex
cgitb.enable()
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print 'Hello'
CMD = '/usr/bin/python -u /path/to/file/filename.py -c %s -r'
cmd = CMD % 'somearg'
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, status = proc.communicate()
print '<pre>%s</pre>' % output
```

and works only after i take out the `subprocess.Popen()` part. 
Strange thing is this code used to work before and I don't remember making any change recently that may have messed with it. Also the subprocess.Popen() part works perfectly from python shell, so the code is correct. I am stuck in finding what is making the page load forever. I have searched for solutions on web but cant find one. Looking for suggestions to solve this. Thanks

Comment: add logging to find out where your cgi script stuck. Use `stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True` to avoid inheriting (possibly closed) standard fds from the parent.

Answer (score -1):

CMD is missing '\n'.

```
CMD = '/usr/bin/python -u /path/to/file/filename.py -c %s -r\n'
```

Comment: So what? It does not do anythig to solve the problem.